# How to create a dictionary from two lists of different sizes?

Tags: python

I have a list of symbols:

```
symbols_list = ['*','†','‡','§','¶','#']
```

and a longer list of elements as:

```
note_list = ['a','b','c','d'.....'z']
```

I want to join them in a dictionary to look like this:

```
{'*':'a','†':'b','‡':'c','§':'d','¶':'e','#':'f','**':'g','††':'h'...'***':'m'...etc. }
```

so basically the `symbols_list` values would repeat as *, **, ***, **** etc.

I tried to just get the `symbols_list` to be the same length at first using:

```
for a in range(0,math.ceil(len(note_list)/len(symbols_list))):
   symbols_list.append(symbols_list[a]+symbols_list[a])
```

but it ended up doubling the elements each iteration instead of just adding one character each time

```
['*',
 '†',
 '‡',
 '§',
 '¶',
 '#',
 '**',
 '††',
 '‡‡',
 '§§',
 '¶¶',
 '##',
 '****',
 '††††',
 '‡‡‡‡',
 '§§§§',
 '¶¶¶¶',
 '####',
 '********',
 '††††††††',
 '‡‡‡‡‡‡‡‡',
 '§§§§§§§§',
 '¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶',
 '########',
 '****************']
```

I thought it would be easier to make the `symbols_list` the same size first, and then combine them into a dictionary.

Comment: You append `symbols_list[a]+symbols_list[a]`, so of course it will double each time. Since you just want to append the _first character_ to the previous symbol, why not just do `symbols_list[a]+symbols_list[a][0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe do it like this:

```
new_symbols_list = []
for i in range(len(note_list)//len(symbols_list)+1):
    new_symbols_list += [k*(i+1) for k in symbols_list]
output = {s: l for s, l in zip(new_symbols_list[:len(note_list)], note_list)}

>>> output
{'*': 'a',
 '†': 'b',
 '‡': 'c',
 '§': 'd',
 '¶': 'e',
 '#': 'f',
 '**': 'g',
 '††': 'h',
 '‡‡': 'i',
 '§§': 'j',
 '¶¶': 'k',
 '##': 'l',
 '***': 'm',
 '†††': 'n',
 '‡‡‡': 'o',
 '§§§': 'p',
 '¶¶¶': 'q',
 '###': 'r',
 '****': 's',
 '††††': 't',
 '‡‡‡‡': 'u',
 '§§§§': 'v',
 '¶¶¶¶': 'w',
 '####': 'x',
 '*****': 'y',
 '†††††': 'z'}
```

Comment: How would I change it if I wanted the keys/values pairs to be reversed in the dictionary?

Comment: output = {l: s for s, l in zip(new_symbols_list[:len(note_list)], note_list)}

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't resist trying to do it with `itertools`.

```py
from itertools import chain, count

# yields *, †, ... **, ††, ... infinitely
symbol_generator = chain.from_iterable(((i*x for x in symbols_list) for i in count(1)))

{s:c for s,c in zip(symbol_generator, abc)}
```

```py
{'*': 'a',
 '†': 'b',
 '‡': 'c',
 '§': 'd',
 '¶': 'e',
 '#': 'f',
 '**': 'g',
 '††': 'h',
 '‡‡': 'i',
 '§§': 'j',
 '¶¶': 'k',
 '##': 'l',
 '***': 'm',
 '†††': 'n',
 '‡‡‡': 'o',
 '§§§': 'p',
 '¶¶¶': 'q',
 '###': 'r',
 '****': 's',
 '††††': 't',
 '‡‡‡‡': 'u',
 '§§§§': 'v',
 '¶¶¶¶': 'w',
 '####': 'x',
 '*****': 'y',
 '†††††': 'z'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for a in range(0,math.ceil(len(note_list)/len(symbols_list))):
   symbols_list.append(symbols_list[a]+symbols_list[a])
```

You append `symbols_list[a]+symbols_list[a]`, which essentially *doubles* `symbols_list[a]`. You just want to add the *first character* of `symbols_list[a]` to itself, so do

```
for a in range(0,math.ceil(len(note_list)/len(symbols_list))):
   symbols_list.append(symbols_list[a]+symbols_list[a][0])
```

Comment: This doesn't repeat the entire list though. It only adds 4 elements to `symbols_list`

Comment: @not_speshal I'm not sure how OP runs their snippet, but if the snippet they provided gives the output they provided in whatever context it is being executed, this should do what they expect (as they confirmed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550520/how-to-create-a-dictionary-from-two-lists-of-different-sizes/68550747#comment121149032_68550520)). Your approach is much better though, and it would be what I would do if I had to write this code. My suggestion was simply so that OP can use as much of their own code as possible

Comment: Yup, the code they provided doesn't generate the output they have :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a oneliner:

```
{ (int(i/len(symbols_list))+1)*symbols_list[i%len(symbols_list)] : e for i, e in enumerate(note_list) }
```